# Only display one radio button value for two value radio button

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a **Status** radio button consists of Active and Inactive. For now, when a radio button is displayed, it will show both Active and Inactive as below.

[image: gambo]

My question is, how can I want to display only one status only. How can I set if radio button true, then it displays only one either Active/Inactive only? Thanks for any help!

#### Update

I have success show only one status, but when on edit mode, it not showing radio button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the field name for your radio button is 'Status'.

I'm assuming that when you say "if radio button true", you really mean "if one of the two values for the radio button is selected".  I.e., you mean it's not blank.

You need a computed-for-display text field. I'll call it ShowStatusValue. You can call it whatever you want. Put it immediately below your radio button. Set the field value formula to

```
Status
```

Click on your radio button and bring up the field properties box and click on the hide-When tab.  Put a check in the 'Hide paragraph when formula is true' box and set the formula to

```
! Status = ""
```

Now click on the ShowStatusValue field, bring up the field properties, go to the hide-when tab, click on the 'Hide paragraph when formula is true' box, and set the formula to

```
Status = ""
```

Comment: Okay I have update now and it show as one status only. But when I want to edit, it now showing the radio button. How can I enable the radio button when on edit mode?

Comment: Change the hide-when formula for the radio button to ! (Status = "") | @IsDocBeingEdited ).  You're also going to have to change the hide-when formula for the ShowStatusValue field. You should be able to work out what the required change is.

Comment: I've insert new formula using @IsDocBeingEdited for radio button and ShowStatusValue field but edit mode still cannot be edit.

Comment: I missed a parenthesis above.  It should be ! ( ( Status = "" ) | @IsDocBeingEdited )

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two statuses, Active and Inactive, why don't you use a simple checkbox:

Active: |_|

If you have more than one status, and the logic in your form depends on the status (e.g. for some form of workflow), I prefer to use separate buttons for changing the status, so you'd need two buttons (or more) named with the new status, and displayed only when the status change is allowed.